# HTML-CSS решение для заголовка с полосами вокруг

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, теги

[image: Такой вид заголовка корректен]
Сейчас такой заголовок задается через класс к заголовку H и далее текст обрамляется тегом em
Специалист говорит, что такой вид сделать чистым H (без класса и em'ки) нереально. Получается только сделать нижнее подчеркивание (боковые полосы навылет по центру заголовка становятся ниже заголовка, т.к. в них задан параметр top: 20px;)
Может быть инструмент какой-то все же есть?
Речь идет о таких URL с H1:
1. http://cx92311.tmweb.ru/obsledovanie-fundamentov-zdanij-i-sooruzhenij/
2. http://test.zlx.ru/obsledovanie-zdanij-i-sooruzheniy/obsledovanie-fundamentov-zdanij-i-sooruzhenij/

Comment: ни чё не понял, надо по бокам h1-h6 сделать полосы?

Comment: Нужно предложить вариант, чтобы полосы и «чистый» h1 были отдельными?

Comment: Надо предложить такой вариант чистого H1, который при этом давал бы полосы по бокам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.head-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.head-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-style: italic;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="head-wrap">
  <h1>Заголовок Заголовок</h1>
</div>
```

---

```css
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    h1 {
      position: relative;
      margin: 50px 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      font-style: italic;
      
      &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 0;
        width: 45vw;
        height: 1px;
        background: #000;
      }
      
      &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 0;
        width: 45vw;
        height: 1px;
        background: #000;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#title {
 border:none;
 border-top:1px solid #ccc;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 
}
```

```html
<fieldset id = title>
  <legend><h1>Title</h1></legend>
</fieldset>
```